# Setup Fedena on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-8, rubygems, fedena

I am trying to setup Fedena project on windows 8. I have followed steps mentioned in official website. http://www.projectfedena.org/install . But while creating database it throws an error. 
Step is `Run the command "rake db:create". This will create the required database.`
Error facing : 
    C:\fedena>rake db:create --trace
    (in C:/fedena)
    rake aborted!
    uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/depende
ncies.rb:55
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original
_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original
_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:18
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original
_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/fedena/Rakefile:10
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakef
ile'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'

C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_excep
tion_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'

C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_excep
tion_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because libmysql.dll is not the right version. You have to install the correct version from MySQL 5. If that doesn't work then install Connector C 6.0.2 and transfer the libmysql.dll and drop it in Ruby/bin